# Execute html() (or text() ) method only after hide() sequence is complete

Tags: jquery, onclick, synchronization, show-hide, jquery-callback

I have a problem with a jquery function, here the code:

```
$(".productUlContainer li.item_thumb").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var actual = this;

    //find the 5th element
    thisLi = $(this).index() + 1;
    thisLink = $(this).find(".bridalLink");
    nLi = parseInt(thisLi/5 + 1);
    nLi*=5;
    $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child(5n)").html("");
    $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").html( $("#html-results > div").html() );

    //Data set
    var thisLinkTitle = thisLink.attr("title");
    var thisLinkPrice = thisLink.find(".item_price").data("price");
    var thisLinkImgPath = thisLink.find(".promo").attr("src");

    //Manage open/close effect
    if ( previous != actual )
    {       
        $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").hide(3000, function(){

            /* Fill big box with clicked product details... */

            $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").find($(".itemName")).text( thisLinkTitle );
            $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").find($(".price")).text( thisLinkPrice );
            $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").find($(".imgCollectionBridal")).attr("src", thisLinkImgPath );

            $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").show(3000, function(){
                previous=actual;
            });
        });

    }
    else
    {
        $(".productUlContainer li:nth-child("+nLi+")").hide(3000, function(){
            previous=false;
        });
    }

});
```

A part the code structure that is very complex and was not made by me, the final result should be related to a div that shows an enlarged image and information of a clicked thumbnail.
As you can see, the function tries to hide an eventual already open div, and AFTER it should change its content with the new clicked thumbnail.

In my opinion, placing these 3 rows INSIDE callback function of hide() should change the content only after hiding sequence is complete, but is not so. During runtime, a click will start hiding sequence but conten change starts just immediately, not after hiding is complete...

Can you tell me why?
Thank you

Comment: Could you reproduce this on jsfiddle because what you describe shouldn't happen

Comment: it it a very nested and complex code... it is the reason for which I posted only JS code.... it could not be so necessary.... :-)

Comment: Check at least if click event is not fired more than one each time you click. Looks like your error comes from your 'nested and complex code'.